# Rails-"Undefined local variable or method 'activerecord' " error when trying to create database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

This is probably a really silly mistake but I'm stuck and can't figure out the issue.

I have a schema file that, as far as I understand, should be used by Rails to create a DB.

I am running the rake commands `reset`, `setup`, etc. (`drop`ing the DB in between commands, if it worked partially) and getting the following error: `NameError: Undefined local variable or method 'activerecord' from Main:Object`.

The first line of the trace points to the first line of the schema file:

```
activerecord::schema.define(version: _____) do
```

What am I missing/forgetting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That'll be `ActiveRecord::Schema` -- you can find more information here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Schema.html

Comment: Ah, I feel so intelligent… :P
Thanks!